# Extract data from webpage to Excel

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I tried to automate this portal, but since I have a trouble due to new to UiPath.

[This is a URL](https://tia.officialbuyersguide.net/SearchResult.asp?city=&cid=3&state=&country=&PID=)

Have to extract CompanyName,BrokerName,Address,Phone into Excel for a number of records as per user input.

Comment: Please do the tutorials first. The whole is thing is easily done via the internal scraping feature. It's easy and intuitive to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since that client data is in one element and separated by breaks (br) I would suggest to still use the Scrape Data feature, (pick the first and second data set-group) and pull in the data set as-is; so its in block format separated by new lines. 
Then iterate through the results, do a split string array on the results, iterate through the string array and evaluate each line using regex. If an address match or email match or phone..etc.. Then handle it from there, You could dump the results into a temp data table and then dump the results into excel.

Granted there might need to be some fluff on your regexpressions and it might miss a few, but it would be a good start. 
Hope that helps get you started

Comment: Thank you guys, but i am new to this i tried upto my knowledge...anyone please share me the workflow screenshots...

Comment: There you can see a tutorials and prepared examples https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/about-data-scraping